# What are the trainable parameters in a deep Gaussian process?

Tags: gaussian-process

I haven't really found any good, intuitive introduction to deep Gaussian processes (DGPs), and while I think I grasp the basic principles of how inference works, I'm struggling a bit with understanding exactly what it is the DGP learns.

So, what are the trainable (or learnable) parameters in a DGP? Is it the values of the stochastic vectors in the hidden layers? The covariance functions in the various layers? Both of them? Also, do you learn one stochastic vector per hidden layer for each input, or do yo learn a fixed number of stochastic vectors per hidden layer disregarding of the number of inputs?